# SYNC-Bluetooth Audio 'jumbled' on car start

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, bluetooth, audio

I have an iPhone 4 and a 2011 Mustang with SYNC. The system works fairly well (outside Of the connection issues many others have experienced) but I have an annoying problem whenever I start my vehicle (maybe 95% of the time).

Upon starting the vehicle, Bluetooth Audio comes on and begins playing my music from my phone. However, for the first ten seconds or so, the sound is jumbled/garbled in a peculiar way: it's really sped up for a second or so, and then silent for a second or so, then sped up etc. It does this cycle about 3-5 times before it finally starts playing normally. If I'm listening to a Car Talk podcast, it might sound something like this:

"Yourelisteningtoc............artalkonnation............alpublicradiowithcl.............ickandclackthetap............pet brothers, and on today's show..."

It's like pinching a hose for a second, and then letting go and having a bunch of words come out at once, then pinching it again.

Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why't don't you use a direct USB connection?  But with that said, I cannot say I've experienced what you have with the 2012 Mustang rental car I had when using Bluetooth.  Any chance of there being a firmware update for SYNC?

Comment: The short answer is that I find the USB connection inconvenient relative to the Bluetooth. (I have to remove my case to make the connection.) I have contacted the dealer and will be taking it in to check for a firmware update tomorrow morning. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when a vehicle cranks the engine there is a lot of stress on the electrical system, in some cases the power supply to ECUs, such as the SYNC module or the ACM can go below the minimum required for them to function, so straight after a crank they can be doing a lot of initialising processes at the same time as trying to play your audio.

I'm sure that the SYNC module uses a 400MHz processor, which isn't really that powerful compared to modules that other automotive manufacturers are using.